# How to avoid SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, awk

I want to write a python script that allows me to extract part of text from multiple files in a directory and save them in a new file. I am trying to use subprocess module but in the specific code I am using awk and for that reason system gives me the syntax error:`SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.Could you tell me how I can avoid this? Here is the code I wrote:

```
import subprocess as sp

f = open(go_term_file, "a")

cmd = "awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN {print "Genome  GO_term"} {print $1 "\t" $14}' | grep "GO:" | uniq"

for file in glob.glob("*_protein.faa.tsv"):
        file_data = open(file, "r")
        data = file_data.read()
        go_terms = sp.call(cmd.split())
        f.write(go_terms)
f.close()
```

I have tried writing the `\t` as `\\t` but couldnt avoid the syntax error.

ADDITIONAL NOTE:
Here is the sample input:

```
MGA_1946|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_19420   d58ff50ceda18d9b393a7d3694995f79    526 Pfam    PF01433 Peptidase family M1 domain  6   87  6.9E-16 T   07-01-2020  IPR014782   Peptidase M1, membrane alanine aminopeptidase   GO:0008237|GO:0008270
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350   83a22d41925835b06417f1e7e7b4f5e1    660 SUPERFAMILY SSF47323        444 645 1.74E-53    T   07-01-2020  IPR009080   Aminoacyl-tRNA synthetase, class Ia, anticodon-binding  GO:0000166|GO:0004812|GO:0005524|GO:0006418
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350   83a22d41925835b06417f1e7e7b4f5e1    660 Gene3D  G3DSA:3.90.740.10       45  185 2.0E-55 T   07-01-2020  IPR009008   Valyl/Leucyl/Isoleucyl-tRNA synthetase, editing domain  GO:0002161|GO:0006418
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350   83a22d41925835b06417f1e7e7b4f5e1    660 Pfam    PF00133 tRNA synthetases class I (I, L, M and V)    2   424 4.6E-156T07-01-2020 IPR002300   Aminoacyl-tRNA synthetase, class Ia GO:0000166|GO:0004812|GO:0005524|GO:0006418
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350   83a22d41925835b06417f1e7e7b4f5e1    660 PRINTS  PR00986 Valyl-tRNA synthetase signature 336 354 4.8E-30 T   07-01-2020  IPR002303   Valine-tRNA ligase  GO:0000166|GO:0004832|GO:0005524|GO:0006438
```

and this is the sample output:

```
MGA_1946|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_19420 GO:0008237|GO:0008270
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350 GO:0000166|GO:0004812|GO:0005524|GO:0006418
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350 GO:0002161|GO:0006418
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350 GO:0000166|GO:0004812|GO:0005524|GO:0006418
MGA_2039|00002511_S689_QC_contigs.fasta_20350 GO:0000166|GO:0004832|GO:0005524|GO:0006438
```

And I want to make one big output by using the for loop over about 100 other files like the sample input

Comment: Did you see the syntax highlighting? `\t` is not in `" ... "`.

Comment: I believe you need to escape your`"` inside your cmd value. By which we are letting python know to take this character literal meaning only.

Comment: Also if you could add sample input and sample output in your post I am pretty sure you may not need uniq and grep in your shell command too.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the right way to do whatever you're doing in python is to spawn a process with a shell pipleine of awk, grep, and other commands.

Comment: I have appended the sample input and sample output in the code above, thanks.

Comment: The sample input does not contain tabs at all so it's hard to try to reproduce or test anything. Visually it looks like the data has 10 tab-separated columns. Is your data incorrect or should the code actually examine the 10th field instead of the 14th? (Unfortunately, Stack Overflow makes it hard to submit text with literal tabs, but it _can_ be done.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure-Python reimplementation.

```
with open(go_term_file, "a") as f:
    for file in glob.glob("*_protein.faa.tsv"):
        f.write("Genome GO_term\n")
        with open(file, "r") as file_data:
            seen = set()
            for line in file_data:
                fields = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
                try:
                    value = "{0}\t{1}\n".format(fields[0], fields[13]])
                except IndexError:
                    continue
                if "GO:" in value:
                    if value not in seen:
                        f.write(value)
                    seen.add(value)
```

The Awk script too would benefit from checking for `GO:` already in the Awk part before printing anything at all.

Notice that this fixes several bugs in your Python code as well.

The output from `subprocess.call()` is simply displayed on standard output, and is not available to Python at all; the return value you get from `call` is the shell pipeline's return code (0 for success, other numbers mean `uniq` failed or there was a shell parsing error). If you want to process the output from a subprocess, use `subprocess.check_output()` or its modern replacement, `subprocess.run()`.

You were also not doing anything with the `data` you read in, and the shell pipeline was not receiving any input, either.

Stylistically, we prefer the `with` context manager over explicitly opening and closing files (you forgot to close `file_data`, too).

Your code would write `Genome GO_term` once per input file; I preserved that logic, but am guessing perhaps you didn't really want it to work that way. The `grep` in your original would discard this output; of course, if you really don't want it, don't print it in the first place.

Similarly, I'll point out that the `uniq` would run once per input file, so if multiple input files contained the same value, you would get duplicates. If that's not what you want, creating the empty `seen` set outside the `for` loop instead makes it global.

... This would not have been too hard to fix in a shell script, either; just run Awk on all the input files in one go. Actually then you would not need Python here at all (or, as noted above, `grep`).

```sh
awk -F "\t" 'FNR==1 {print "Genome  GO_term"}
  $14 ~ /GO:/ {print $1 "\t" $14}' *_protein.faa.tsv |
uniq
```

Note also that `uniq` only removes *adjacent* identical lines. In the Python code, I assumed you really want each output line to be unique, but this should be easy to change back (just remember the previous printed value, and don't print if this one is identical). Conversely, it would not be hard to refactor the Awk script to not print repeats using very similar logic, though of course the Awk syntax will be quite different from how it looks in Python.

To contrast these two approaches, note how much more succinct the Awk code is. Even if you extended it to quadruple its size and complexity, it would still be quite small and easy to understand. But then that's roughly the limit of what makes sense to do in Awk; if you plan to make this part of a bigger, more complex program, Python is more suitable for that. Also, the Python code, in all its explicitness, is quite easy to understand even if you don't use the language every day. I'm afraid the same cannot be said about Awk.  The explicit structure of the Python code also makes it easy to see which part might need to be changed if you reveal or discover new requirements.

Comment: Thank you tripleee, I really appreciate your help! I ran your code and it gave me the ```IndexError: list index out of range``` . I forgot to mention, but some of the records don't have the 13th field and I assume that is the reason I am getting this error. How can I adapt this so that I can take out only the records that have 13th field? And yes, I only want the Genome Go_term on the very top of the file, so I fixed it, thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a `try`/`except` to catch and bypass the `IndexError`. For what it's worth, index 13 is the 14th field (Python numbers things from zero, while Awk starts at 1).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import subprocess as sp

f = open(go_term_file, "a")

cmd = "awk -F \"\t\" 'BEGIN {print \"Genome  GO_term\"} {print $1 \"\t\" $14}' | grep \"GO:\" | uniq"

for file in glob.glob("*_protein.faa.tsv"):
        file_data = open(file, "r")
        data = file_data.read()
        go_terms = sp.call(cmd.split())
        f.write(go_terms)
f.close()
```

Everything should be put in quotes or it's real python code (`\` is **line continuation character** in python). Use `\"` to put a double quote in a double-quoted string.

Comment: Python offers triple quotes precisely so you don't have to escape literal quotes so much.